# RichTextBox links don't do anything

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, .net-2.0, richtextbox

I have a `RichTextBox` control on a form with some text, some of which are URLs.  The `DetectUrls` property is set to `true`.  The control properly detects my URLs (they're blue, underlined and the cursor changes to a hand when I hover them).  However, when I click on them nothing happens (double-click and ctrl+click are similarly ineffective).  I've set the `ReadOnly` property to `true`, not sure if that matters.  Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is an event you hook up to that is fired when links are clicked on.

Hook up to that

```
public event LinkClickedEventHandler LinkClicked;

OnLinkClicked
```

Comment: Ahh, not sure how I missed that, it is pretty obvious.  Do you know how to open the default browser with the URL that was clicked in that event?

Comment: Try Process.Start(e.LinkText).